# Merge DataTable c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, merge

I'm trying to merge two sheets from an excel file to one DataTable.

The function builds and run, but when im trying to fetch data from the second table nothing happens. ( it works from the first sheet )

This is what i have for the moment. 
Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
 private static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
    {
        //open file and returns as Stream
        FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        //Createopenxmlreader via ExcelReaderFactory
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream); //.xlsx
        //Set the First Row as Column Name
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        //Return as DataSet
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        //Get all the Tables
        DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
        //Store it in DataTable

        DataTable resultTable1 = table["Sheet1"];
        DataTable resultTable2 = table["Extra"];
        DataTable dtAll = resultTable1.Copy();
        dtAll.Merge(resultTable2);

        //return
        return dtAll;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715976/Solutions-to-Merge-Multiple-Excel-Worksheets-int

Comment: So in other words `table["Extra"]` is an empty DataTable? Then your issue is not related to merging DataTables but to extracting DataTables from excel-sheets with this library: https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: @TimSchmelter well table extra behave likes its empty,but it not :) will read the link. thanks.